# Are there CScope-style source browsers for other languages besides C/C++ on Windows?

Tags: vim

I'm specifically interested in tools that can be plugged into Vim to allow CScope-style source browsing (1-2 keystroke commands to locate function definitions, callers, global symbols and so on) for languages besides C/C++ such as Java and C# (since Vim and Cscope already integrate very well for browsing C/C++). I'm not interested in IDE-based tools since I know Microsoft and other vendors already address that space -- I prefer to use Vim for editing and browsing, but but don't know of tools for C# and/or Java that give me the same power as CScope.

The original answer to this question included a pointer to the CSWrapper application which apparently fixes a bug that some users experience integrating Vim and CScope. However, my Vim/CScope installation works fine; I'm just trying to expand the functionality to allow using Vim to edit code in other languages.

Comment: For python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718868/using-cscope-to-browse-python-code-with-vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CScope does work for Java.

From http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html:

> Although Cscope was originally intended only for use with C code, it's
>   actually a very flexible tool that works well with languages like C++
>   and Java. You can think of it as a generic 'grep' database, with the
>   ability to recognize certain additional constructs like function calls
>   and variable definitions. By default Cscope only parses C, lex, and
>   yacc files (.c, .h, .l, .y) in the current directory (and
>   subdirectories, if you pass the -R flag), and there's currently no way
>   to change that list of file extensions (yes, we ought to change that).
>   So instead you have to make a list of the files that you want to
>   parse, and call it 'cscope.files' (you can call it anything you want
>   if you invoke 'cscope -i foofile'). An easy (and very flexible) way to
>   do this is via the trusty Unix 'find' command:

```
find . -name '*.java' > cscope.files
```

> Now run 'cscope -b' to rebuild the database (the -b just builds the
>   database without launching the Cscope GUI), and you'll be able to
>   browse all the symbols in your Java files. Apparently there are folks
>   out there using Cscope to browse and edit large volumes of
>   documentation files, which shows how flexible Cscope's parser is.

Answer (score 8):

Claiming that Cscope supports Java is an extreme stretch.  It seems to treat a method like a function, so it has no idea that A.foo(), A.foo(Object) and B.foo() are all different.  This is a big problem with a large code base (including third-party libraries) with many same-named methods.  (I haven't looked at the Cscope source, but this is what I found trying the latest Cscope, version 15.7a-3.3 from Debian unstable.)

I tried Cscope on a large Java project, and it was not at all useful to me due to this limitation.  It's sad that we cannot get a quick answer to a basic question like "who calls this method", using free software outside of the big IDEs, but we may as well accept it.  (I would love it if I'm wrong.  I resort to hacks like commenting out the method and recompiling.)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party here, but my https://github.com/eapache/starscope/ project provides a nice framework for generating cscope databases for more languages. Currently it supports Ruby and Go, and Javascript is in progress. Adding Java/C# shouldn't be that difficult.

Edit: Javascript is now fully supported.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!

Comment: It's surprisingly slow in building database, for a moderate size project I see ETA of 5 Hrs

Comment: For what language? For JavaScript you may need to install a more efficient execjs runtime (https://github.com/rails/execjs) e.g. therubyracer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew - trying to get a call hierarchy for a method returns all calls of the same name, even if they are from a different class.

You can use Eclim to plug Eclipse into VIM

http://eclim.org/

which supportrs call hierarchy

http://eclim.org/vim/java/inspection.html#call-hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1783

You can also mimic some CScope functionality in your own .vimrc file by using the various flavors of [map](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html).