# Using cscope to browse Python code with VIM?

Tags: python, vim, editor, cscope

Has anyone managed successfully using `cscope` with Python code? I have VIM 7.2 and the latest version of `cscope` installed, however it doesn't get my code's tags correctly (always off by a couple of lines). I tried the `pycscope` script but its output isn't supported by the modern version of `cscope`.

Any ideas? Or an alternative for browsing Python code with VIM? (I'm specifically interested in the extra features `cscope` offers beyond the simple tags of `ctags`)

Comment: Have you considered simply fixing pycscope? I haven't looked at what needs to be done, but I can't imagine it being too difficult. Also, you may want to update your question to mention that, as your blog post says, cscope is thrown off by Python comments.

Comment: @ssokolow: The problem with fixing `pycscope` is that the "DB" format `cscope` uses isn't documented, and according to the maintainer of `cscope` this is by design

Comment: Ahh. That WOULD be unpleasant. I'd have to think about what solution I'd attempt in that situation.

Comment: Even trying to modify cscope is a disaster.  I can find the code used to identify comments, but I think it would be a mess to try and include # and """ in the comment code.  Perhaps the easiest way would be to preprocess the source files and strip the comments (replacing them with blank lines).  But again, that's not very fun because cscope doesn't work with standard input.

Comment: Doxygen natively supports only C and Java, but through PREFILTER option it is able to process any programming language files. Filtering app needs to be written for the language. I also submitted (as [patch #3413344](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3413344&group_id=6556&atid=306556)), prefilter option to ctags. Maybe it would be nice to have it in cscope also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. From a correspondence with the maintainer of `cscope`, this tool isn't designed to work with Python, and there are no plans to implement that compatibility. Whatever works now, apparently works by mistake, and there is no promise whatsoever that it will keep working.
2. It appears I've been using an out-of-date version of `pycscope`. The latest version 0.3 is supported by the `cscope` DB. The author of `pycscope` told me that he figured out the output format for the `cscope` DB from reading the source code of `cscope`. That format isn't documented, on purpose, but nevertheless it currently works with `pycsope` 0.3, which is the solution I'll be using.

---

I'm going to accept this answer since unfortunately no other answer provided help even after bounty was declared. No answers are upvoted, so I honestly have no idea where the bounty will go.

Comment: *shrugs*  You wanted an alternative to cscope, which would be idutils. They perform similar tasks.

Comment: @chiggsy: AFAIU idutils is more a replacement for `grep` than for `cscope`

Answer (score 18):

EDIT:  I'm going to run through the process step by step:

#### Preparing the sources:

exhuberant ctags, has an option: -x

```
   Alternatively,  ctags  can generate a cross reference file which lists,
   in human readable form, information about the  various  source  objects
   found in a set of language files.
```

This is the key to the problem:

```
 ctags -x $(ls **/*.py);                  # replace with find if no zsh
```

will give you your database of source objects in a known, format, described under

```
 man ctags;                               # make sure you use exuberant ctags!
```

Gnu Global is not limited to only the "out of the box" type of files.  Any regular file format will serve.

Also, you can use gtags-cscope, which comes with global as mentioned in section 3.7 of the manual, for a possible shortcut using gtags.   You'll end up with an input of a  ctags tabular file which Global/gtags  can parse to get your objects,  or you can use the source for pycscope together with your ctags file of known format to get an input for the vim cscope commands in

if_cscope.txt.

Either way it's quite doable.

#### Perhaps you'd prefer idutils?

Definintely possible since

z3c.recipe.tags

on pypi makes use of both ctags and idutils to create tag files for a buildout, which is a method I shall investigate in short while.

Of course, you could always use the greputils script below, it has support for idutils , we know idutils works with python, and if that fails, there is also something called vimentry from this year that also uses python, idutils and vim.

#### Reference links (not complete list):

- [gtags vimscript](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=893), uses Gnu global. updated 2008
- [greputils vimscript](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1062), contains support for the *id idutils, 2005
- [lid vimscript](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=251), Ancient, but this guy is pretty good, his tag and buffer howtos are amazing  2002
- [An updated version of pyscope](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/source/browse/src/tools/pycscope.py), 2010

Hopefully this helps you with your problem, I certainly helped me.  I would  have been quite sad tonight with a maggoty pycscope.

Comment: gnu global doesn't support Python, grep utils obviously isn't what I'm looking for... why do you link to pycscope's source code?

Comment: Why do you use `$(ls **/*.py)` instead of `**/*.py` on its own?  AFAIK in zsh they are equivalent, and will both expand to the list of matching files in all subdirectories.

Comment: I've decided to grant you the bounty since you've done a solid amount of research trying to help me solve the problem. Keep up the good work on SO

Comment: "something called vimentry" - is this referring to exVim, which has `your_project.vimentry` files? That's all I could find from googling.

Answer (score 18):

This seems to work for me:

Change to the top directory of your python code.  Create a file called `cscope.files`:

```
find . -name '*.py' > cscope.files

cscope -R
```

You may need to perform a `cscope -b` first if the cross references don't get built properly.

Comment: Great Tip! 
Works with PHP too, for me: ("PHP and cscope in vim"): 
`find . -name '*.php' > cscope.files && cscope -Rb` -- 
`-b` for saving the results (in cscope.out and using them in vim).

Answer (score 2):

There is a wonderful [Python-mode-klen](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) plugin. If you have it and rope (python refactoring library) installed, then going to the definition of a particular term is as simple as `<C-c>g` or `<C-c>rag` (first is filetype mapping, second is a global one). There are much more useful features, some useless for me. All of them are disableable. Features from list of questions found at [cscope-intro](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/if_cscop.txt.html#line51-0):

1. **Where is this symbol used?** <kbd><C-c>f</kbd>. Rather confusing though, as results in quickfix list do show `-` instead of the actual lines (though they point to the correct location). Maybe it will be fixed.
2. **Where is it defined?**, **What is this global symbol's definition?**, **Where is this function in the source files?** <kbd><C-c>g</kbd>
3. **What is <...> global symbol's definition?** <kbd><C-c>raj</kbd>

Not very much, but I am not too experienced user of ropevim.

Comment: I can find <C-c>g in their documentation, but not <C-c>f. Could you please provide a reference, or the actual command that is called when pressing <C-c>f?

Comment: @YoniZohar https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/a92bfa476467822e5723edb689cb1e80c13da52d/plugin/pymode.vim#L221, then https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/a92bfa476467822e5723edb689cb1e80c13da52d/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim#L139. I do not recall where I got this mapping in the first place though, `git log --patch doc/pymode.txt` shows that it was never in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question you got, after browsing the internet, I found a way to fix this:

create a python script: `cscope_scan.py`

```
import os

codeRootDir = os.getcwd()

__revision__ = '0.1'
__author__ = 'lxd'

FILE_TYPE_LIST= ['py']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    f = open('cscope.files','w')
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(codeRootDir):
        for file in files:
            for file_type in FILE_TYPE_LIST:
                if file.split('.')[-1] == file_type:
                    f.write('%s\n' %os.path.join(root,file))
    f.close()
    cmd = 'cscope -bk'
    os.system(cmd)
```

excute this script under you code's root folder, this will generate the `cscope.files` and then excute `cscope -b` I don't know what happens to my computer, the last two lines aren't working well, but I think manually type a `cscope -bk` is acceptable:)

Answer (score 0):

This hack also seems to force cscope to go through Python files:

```
cscope -Rb -s *
```

If you accept that `cscope` is [apparently not designed to work with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718868/using-cscope-to-browse-python-code-with-vim/3779871#3779871).

Superset any language any tool question: [How to find all occurrences of a variable in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616144/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-variable-in-vim)