# how to auto load cscope.out in vim

Tags: vim, cscope

I want to auto load my `cscope.out` in the subdirectory of my project, so I add this scripts in my `.vimrc`, which is as follows:

```
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-

if has("cscope")
    set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
    set csto=1
    set cst
    set csverb
    set cspc=3
    "add any database in current dir
    if filereadable("cscope.out")
        cs add cscope.out
    "else search cscope.out elsewhere
    else
       let cscope_file=findfile("cscope.out", ".;")
        "echo cscope_file
        if !empty(cscope_file) && filereadable(cscope_file)
            exe "cs add" cscope_file
        endif      
     endif
endif
```

it works at first. But every time when I trying to do:

```
:cs find c [tag]
```

The search result will appear in the QuickFix List, but the file which contains the result can not be opened.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Wikia article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_create_and_update_cscope_database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `cscope.out` make sure it to set the correct path prefix. Otherwise it will show you the result but cannot load the file.

example:

```
   cs add ../cscope.out ../
```

so you should change your script to

```
 ...
 else
   let cscope_file=findfile("cscope.out", ".;")
   let cscope_pre=matchstr(cscope_file, ".*/")
   "echo cscope_file
   if !empty(cscope_file) && filereadable(cscope_file)
      exe "cs add" cscope_file cscope_pre
   endif
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.When I use 
:cs show  
I never notice that there is a prepend path there.
And I found another way to make it works, when I generate cscope.file
I use Relative path，When I change to use Absolute path in cscope.file it works very well.

Thanks again