# Why is autoload cscope.out enabled only after opening vim for the second time

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, cscope

What I want to do is to create a new cscope database based on different file types every time I open vim, and then automatically load `cscope.out`

I edit my `.vimrc`, based on this article: [how to auto load cscope.out in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243233/how-to-auto-load-cscope-out-in-vim)

But it only autoloads `cscope.out` the second time I open vim, the first time I open vim, it always show `no cscope connection`

**What should I change?**

Here is my settings:

```
if !filereadable("cscope.out")
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py !find / -name "*.py" > ~/cscope.files; cscope -Rbq -i ~/cscope.files
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.java !find / -name "*.java" > ~/cscope.files; cscope -Rbq -i ~/cscope.files
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.c !find / -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" > ~/cscope.files; cscope -Rbq -i ~/cscope.files
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.cpp !find / -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.h" > ~/cscope.files; cscope -Rbq -i ~/cscope.files
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.hpp !find / -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.h" > ~/cscope.files; cscope -Rbq -i ~/cscope.files
endif

" setting location of cscope db & cscopetag
let CSCOPE_DB="~/cscope.out"                
                                                                              
if has("cscope")
"   set csprg=/usr/local/bin/cscope
    set csto=0
    set cst
    set nocsverb
    " add any database in current directory
    if filereadable("cscope.out")
        cs add cscope.out
    " else add database pointed to by environment
    elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
        cs add $CSCOPE_DB
    endif
    set csverb
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "autocommand" block, you add autocommands to the default autocommand group. They will be executed *later*, when you edit a `*.py` file or whatever. At this point, no database is created.

In the "cscope" block, you point `cscope` to a database but no database has been created.

After your `vimrc` is sourced, the `*.py` file is loaded and the database is created but the code in charge of the `cscope` setup has already run so `cscope` doesn't know about your database.

The next time you run Vim, the database is already there because it has been created during the previous run, so code that sets up `cscope` does its job as expected and `cscope` gets a proper database.

You should be able to solve your problem by postponing the `cscope` step to *after* the database has been created, which sounds like a perfect use case for `:help job_start()`.

Comment: In this case, I should use `job_start()` on create `cscope.files` first, then use `job_status()` to assure database has been created. Am I right?

Comment: Something like that. `:help job-exit_cb` might be simpler.